# How to get value from autocomplete textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, autocomplete

Please I need your help. Am finding it difficult to get the value from an autocomplete text field into my modal. It's only picking the character I typed, not the selected content of the textbox. I want to use JavaScript. Here is my code

```js
function Client() 
{
  document.getElementById('client2').value = document.getElementById('client1').value;
}

function Brand()
{
document.getElementsByName('brand2')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('brand1')[0].value;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/index.html">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><label for="client">Client:</label></td>
         <td style="padding:5px"><input type="text" 
            id="client1" placeholder="Enter Client" size="40px" onkeyup="Client();"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label for="Brand">Brand:</label></td>
         <td style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" 
            id="brand" placeholder="Enter Brand" size="40px" name="brand1" onkeyup="Brand();"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <div><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Preview" class="button" onclick="toggleModal()" /> 
   </div>
   <div>
   <h4><label id="lbclient" class="label">*Client:</label><input type= "text" id="client2" readonly 
      size="50px" class="textbox-modal"></h4>
   <h4><label id="lbbrand" class="label">*Brand:</label><input type= "text" name ="brand2" readonly 
      size="50px" class="textbox-modal"></h4>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is related to the `#brand` element ? You are using the `keyup` event which is triggered after each type. You might want to look into the  `blur` event, which will trigger when the field looses focus.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it #brand element that am having problem with. #client is working fine. I had changed onkeyup to onblur, the problem still the same. Am guessing my problem is from the function.
        function Brand(){
 document.getElementsByName('brand2')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('brand1')[0].value;
 
}

Comment: From the example above, everything seams to be working fine, what are you looking for exactly ?

Comment: Everything works fine on my end as well. `blur` should work as well as Nicolas pointed out. `onchange` is another method that should also work.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE, textbox brand (brand1) is autocomplete. That means, when I select a letter, it predict what I want to type, and if I select among the lists, the value I get on brand2 textbox is only the letter I typed to select the autoomplete. Hope you get my problem

Comment: Example, if I type leter "C" brand1 textbox will predict Coca-Cola, Coke etc for me to select among the list, if I type all characters for "Coca-Cola" textbox brand2 will be equal to "Coca-Cola, but if I type letter "C" and and select "Coca-Cola from the list, textbox brand2 only gives me "C", instead of "Coca-Cola". Hope this explain it better

Comment: Any help please?